# Python: Concurrent.Futures Error [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable]

Tags: python, typeerror, python-asyncio, nonetype

So I managed to get asyncio / the Google CSE API to work together.... When I run my code on PyCharm, I am able to print my results out.  However, at the very end of the printed stuff is the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable".

I suspect it has something to do with my list and maybe the loop trying to search for another term even though I'm at the end of the list...

Also.. this is my first question post so feel free to offer suggestions on how to ask questions better as well

Thoughts?

```
searchterms = ['cheese',
    'hippos',
    'whales',
    'beluga']

async def sendQueries(queries, deposit=list()):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor,
                searching(queries)
            )
        ]
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            deposit.append(response.json())
        return deposit

def running():
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(sendQueries(searchterms)))
     loop.close()

print(running())
print(str(time.time() - x))
```

My error can be traced back to "for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):"

For your reference, searching(queries) is simply the function for my Google CSE API call.

Comment: Unrelated: you should read up on [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/). You may run into problems with `deposit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the call to `run_in_executor`:

```
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(
            executor,
            searching(queries)
        )
    ]
```

`run_in_executor` accepts a function to execute. The code doesn't pass it a function, it **calls** a function, `searching`, and passes `run_in_executor` the return value of that call. That has two consequences:

1. the code doesn't work as intended - it invokes the searches one by after the other, not in parallel;
2. it displays an error complaining of an attempt by `run_in_executor` to invoke the `None` return value of `searching(...)`. Confusingly, the error is raised only later, when awaiting the futures returned by `run_in_executor`, by which time all the searches have actually finished.

The correct way to call `run_in_executor` would be something like:

```
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, searching, queries)
    ]
```

Note how the `searching` function is now only *mentioned* rather than *used*.

Also, if you are only using asyncio to invoke synchronous calls in `run_in_executor`, you are not really benefiting from its use. You could get the same effect using threading-based tools from `concurrent.futures` directly, but without the need to adjust your whole program to asyncio. `run_in_executor` is meant to be used sparingly, either for occasional interfacing with legacy APIs that don't provide an async front-end, or for CPU-heavy code which cannot be meaningfully converted to coroutines.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help.  It's definitely working faster now.  I'm getting about 12 search instances in 1.1 seconds instead of the 5 before.  I thought something was sketchy about that time before.....

Comment: This is awesome! It solved my problem even though I was using `with ThreadPoolExecutor as exe: exe.submit`

Answer (score 2):

I got **the same error** with `executor.submit()` also.

```
# not work
futures.append(executor.submit(myfunc(arg1, arg2)))

# works
futures.append(executor.submit(myfunc, arg1, arg2))
```

Thank you guys,